# How to match the international alphabet (English a-z, + non English) with a regular expression?

Tags: regex, unicode

I want to allow only entered data from the English alphabet and from the alphabet from Germany.

Like `öäü` OR France like  `áê` or Chinese like ...

How can I configure my regular expression so it accepts all alphabetical characters from the international alphabet?

Comment: What language or regular expression implementation do you use?

Comment: Chinese "alphabets" aren't `...`!

Answer (score 17):

Since you specifically ask for Unicode, `\p{L}` is the shortcut for a Unicode letter. Not all regex flavors support this syntax, though. .NET, Perl, Java and the JGSoft regex engine will, Python won't, for example.

So, for example `\b\p{L}+\b` will match an entire word of Unicode characters.

Comment: This would be _great_ if it worked in javascript's replace regex, but it doesn't seem to work for me (in chrome, at least). Any ideas?

Comment: @aaaidan: Difficult since JavaScript's built-in regex engine is very limited and does not provide an abstraction like `\p{L}`. You can always create your own character class from all the Unicode letter codepoints (the horror!) or use Steve Levithan's XRegExp library with the Unicode plugin: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/xregexp-unicode-plugin

Comment: In PHP use \p{L} with the `u` modifier for the preg functions

Comment: Does the newer `u` modifier in JavaScript work here? Doesn't seem like it at the moment...

Comment: @DonMcCurdy: To my knowledge, JS regexes remain Unicode-unaware. There is an extension (XRegexp) you can use, though.

Comment: You need to drop the + as this will match and actual plus symbol, seems to work fine without it.

Comment: @MarcNewton: Not in a normal regex. Only within a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) a plus sign will be interpreted literally; in a regex it's a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) meaning "one or more".

Answer (score 1):

It varies. Some languages have a "Unicode" flag which extend `\d`, `\w`, etc. Some support equivalence classes in a range, e.g. `[[=e=]]` matches `e`, `é`, `ê`, etc. The regex documentation for your language or library will explain what options are available.

Answer (score 0):

With [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) it would be `\w`, a "word" character. It also accepts Unicode when configured properly.

Comment: `\w` is not a boundary but the character class of word characters.

Comment: ... and `\b` is the word boundary.

Comment: Indeed, I have modified my original answer. My explanation was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is regex to match all alphabetical letters across international word systems using **Unicode property escapes**:

> Check language support for **Unicode property escapes**, may not be available in older versions, especially web browsers (JavaScript)

TEST STRING

```
!"£$%^&*()_+[]{}'#;@~,./<?>¬``
0123465789
àáâasdäæãåāăąçćčđďèéêëēėęěğǵḧîïíīįìłḿñńǹňôöòóœøōõőṕŕřßśšdsşșťțûüùúūǘůűųẃẍÿýžźż
山人口刀木日月女子馬鳥目水
私金魚煙草莨東京
わたしきんぎょたばことうきょう
ワタシキンギョタバコトウキョウ
קרשתאבגדהוזחטיכ
abcdefghijklmonpqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
©▓±■╣║¢¥
```

**PCRE (PHP) / GoLang** - https://regex101.com/r/iRTxw4/2

Match Letters Only: `\p{L}+`

Match Numbers Only: `\p{N}+`

Match Letters & Numbers: `\p{N}+|\p{L}+`

Match None Letters & Numbers: `[^\p{L}\p{N}]`

**ECMAScript (JavaScript)**

Still figuring this out...

Answer (score 0):

```
/[#\uFE5F\uFF03](?:[\*\+\x2D0-9A-Z_a-z\xA9\xAA\xAE\xB5\xB7\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0300-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037B-\u037D\u037F\u0386-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u0483-\u0487\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0560-\u0588\u0591-\u05BD\u05BF\u05C1\u05C2\u05C4\u05C5\u05C7\u05D0-\u05EA\u05EF-\u05F2\u0610-\u061A\u0620-\u0669\u066E-\u06D3\u06D5-\u06DC\u06DF-\u06E8\u06EA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710-\u074A\u074D-\u07B1\u07C0-\u07F5\u07FA\u07FD\u0800-\u082D\u0840-\u085B\u0860-\u086A\u08A0-\u08B4\u08B6-\u08BD\u08D3-\u08E1\u08E3-\u0963\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0983\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BC-\u09C4\u09C7\u09C8\u09CB-\u09CE\u09D7\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E3\u09E6-\u09F1\u09FC\u09FE\u0A01-\u0A03\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A3C\u0A3E-\u0A42\u0A47\u0A48\u0A4B-\u0A4D\u0A51\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A75\u0A81-\u0A83\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABC-\u0AC5\u0AC7-\u0AC9\u0ACB-\u0ACD\u0AD0\u0AE0-\u0AE3\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0AF9-\u0AFF\u0B01-\u0B03\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3C-\u0B44\u0B47\u0B48\u0B4B-\u0B4D\u0B56\u0B57\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B63\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B82\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BBE-\u0BC2\u0BC6-\u0BC8\u0BCA-\u0BCD\u0BD0\u0BD7\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C00-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D-\u0C44\u0C46-\u0C48\u0C4A-\u0C4D\u0C55\u0C56\u0C58-\u0C5A\u0C60-\u0C63\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C80-\u0C83\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBC-\u0CC4\u0CC6-\u0CC8\u0CCA-\u0CCD\u0CD5\u0CD6\u0CDE\u0CE0-\u0CE3\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D00-\u0D03\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D44\u0D46-\u0D48\u0D4A-\u0D4E\u0D54-\u0D57\u0D5F-\u0D63\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D82\u0D83\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DCA\u0DCF-\u0DD4\u0DD6\u0DD8-\u0DDF\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0DF2\u0DF3\u0E01-\u0E3A\u0E40-\u0E4E\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E86-\u0E8A\u0E8C-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7-\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EC8-\u0ECD\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F18\u0F19\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F35\u0F37\u0F39\u0F3E-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F71-\u0F84\u0F86-\u0F97\u0F99-\u0FBC\u0FC6\u1000-\u1049\u1050-\u109D\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u135D-\u135F\u1369-\u1371\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F5\u13F8-\u13FD\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16EE-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1714\u1720-\u1734\u1740-\u1753\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1772\u1773\u1780-\u17D3\u17D7\u17DC\u17DD\u17E0-\u17E9\u180B-\u180D\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1878\u1880-\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1920-\u192B\u1930-\u193B\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19B0-\u19C9\u19D0-\u19DA\u1A00-\u1A1B\u1A20-\u1A5E\u1A60-\u1A7C\u1A7F-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1AB0-\u1ABD\u1B00-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B6B-\u1B73\u1B80-\u1BF3\u1C00-\u1C37\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1C80-\u1C88\u1C90-\u1CBA\u1CBD-\u1CBF\u1CD0-\u1CD2\u1CD4-\u1CFA\u1D00-\u1DF9\u1DFB-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u200D\u203C\u203F\u2040\u2049\u2054\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u20D0-\u20DC\u20E1\u20E3\u20E5-\u20F0\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2118-\u211D\u2122\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2160-\u2188\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u2648-\u2653\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u267F\u2692-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D7F-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2DE0-\u2DFF\u3005-\u3007\u3021-\u3035\u3038-\u303D\u3041-\u3096\u3099\u309A\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312F\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3297\u3299\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FEF\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA66F\uA674-\uA67D\uA67F-\uA6F1\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA7BF\uA7C2-\uA7C6\uA7F7-\uA827\uA840-\uA873\uA880-\uA8C5\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8E0-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA8FD-\uA92D\uA930-\uA953\uA960-\uA97C\uA980-\uA9C0\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA36\uAA40-\uAA4D\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A-\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEF\uAAF2-\uAAF6\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB67\uAB70-\uABEA\uABEC\uABED\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFC5D\uFC64-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDF9\uFE00-\uFE0F\uFE20-\uFE2F\uFE33\uFE34\uFE4D-\uFE4F\uFE71\uFE73\uFE77\uFE79\uFE7B\uFE7D\uFE7F-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF3F\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]|\uD800[\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDD40-\uDD74\uDDFD\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDEE0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF2D-\uDF4A\uDF50-\uDF7A\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF\uDFD1-\uDFD5]|\uD801[\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDCA0-\uDCA9\uDCB0-\uDCD3\uDCD8-\uDCFB\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67]|\uD802[\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDCE0-\uDCF2\uDCF4\uDCF5\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE\uDDBF\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05\uDE06\uDE0C-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE35\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE3F\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE6\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91]|\uD803[\uDC00-\uDC48\uDC80-\uDCB2\uDCC0-\uDCF2\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD39\uDF00-\uDF1C\uDF27\uDF30-\uDF50\uDFE0-\uDFF6]|\uD804[\uDC00-\uDC46\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDC7F-\uDCBA\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDD00-\uDD34\uDD36-\uDD3F\uDD44-\uDD46\uDD50-\uDD73\uDD76\uDD80-\uDDC4\uDDC9-\uDDCC\uDDD0-\uDDDA\uDDDC\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE37\uDE3E\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE88\uDE8A-\uDE8D\uDE8F-\uDE9D\uDE9F-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEEA\uDEF0-\uDEF9\uDF00-\uDF03\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3B-\uDF44\uDF47\uDF48\uDF4B-\uDF4D\uDF50\uDF57\uDF5D-\uDF63\uDF66-\uDF6C\uDF70-\uDF74]|\uD805[\uDC00-\uDC4A\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC5E\uDC5F\uDC80-\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDD80-\uDDB5\uDDB8-\uDDC0\uDDD8-\uDDDD\uDE00-\uDE40\uDE44\uDE50-\uDE59\uDE80-\uDEB8\uDEC0-\uDEC9\uDF00-\uDF1A\uDF1D-\uDF2B\uDF30-\uDF39]|\uD806[\uDC00-\uDC3A\uDCA0-\uDCE9\uDCFF\uDDA0-\uDDA7\uDDAA-\uDDD7\uDDDA-\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE4\uDE00-\uDE3E\uDE47\uDE50-\uDE99\uDE9D\uDEC0-\uDEF8]|\uD807[\uDC00-\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC36\uDC38-\uDC40\uDC50-\uDC59\uDC72-\uDC8F\uDC92-\uDCA7\uDCA9-\uDCB6\uDD00-\uDD06\uDD08\uDD09\uDD0B-\uDD36\uDD3A\uDD3C\uDD3D\uDD3F-\uDD47\uDD50-\uDD59\uDD60-\uDD65\uDD67\uDD68\uDD6A-\uDD8E\uDD90\uDD91\uDD93-\uDD98\uDDA0-\uDDA9\uDEE0-\uDEF6]|\uD808[\uDC00-\uDF99]|\uD809[\uDC00-\uDC6E\uDC80-\uDD43]|[\uD80C\uD81C-\uD820\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD86C\uD86F-\uD872\uD874-\uD879][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD80D[\uDC00-\uDC2E]|\uD811[\uDC00-\uDE46]|\uD81A[\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDE60-\uDE69\uDED0-\uDEED\uDEF0-\uDEF4\uDF00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF50-\uDF59\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F]|\uD81B[\uDE40-\uDE7F\uDF00-\uDF4A\uDF4F-\uDF87\uDF8F-\uDF9F\uDFE0\uDFE1\uDFE3]|\uD821[\uDC00-\uDFF7]|\uD822[\uDC00-\uDEF2]|\uD82C[\uDC00-\uDD1E\uDD50-\uDD52\uDD64-\uDD67\uDD70-\uDEFB]|\uD82F[\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99\uDC9D\uDC9E]|\uD834[\uDD65-\uDD69\uDD6D-\uDD72\uDD7B-\uDD82\uDD85-\uDD8B\uDDAA-\uDDAD\uDE42-\uDE44]|\uD835[\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB\uDFCE-\uDFFF]|\uD836[\uDE00-\uDE36\uDE3B-\uDE6C\uDE75\uDE84\uDE9B-\uDE9F\uDEA1-\uDEAF]|\uD838[\uDC00-\uDC06\uDC08-\uDC18\uDC1B-\uDC21\uDC23\uDC24\uDC26-\uDC2A\uDD00-\uDD2C\uDD30-\uDD3D\uDD40-\uDD49\uDD4E\uDEC0-\uDEF9]|\uD83A[\uDC00-\uDCC4\uDCD0-\uDCD6\uDD00-\uDD4B\uDD50-\uDD59]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB]|\uD83C[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDDE6-\uDDFF\uDE01\uDE02\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF93\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E-\uDFF0\uDFF3-\uDFF5\uDFF7-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDCFD\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD49-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73-\uDD7A\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96\uDDA4\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA-\uDE4F\uDE80-\uDEC5\uDECB-\uDED2\uDED5\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF0\uDEF3-\uDEFA\uDFE0-\uDFEB]|\uD83E[\uDD0D-\uDD3A\uDD3C-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD71\uDD73-\uDD76\uDD7A-\uDDA2\uDDA5-\uDDAA\uDDAE-\uDDCA\uDDCD-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE73\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE82\uDE90-\uDE95]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]|\uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D\uDC20-\uDFFF]|\uD873[\uDC00-\uDEA1\uDEB0-\uDFFF]|\uD87A[\uDC00-\uDFE0]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D]|\uDB40[\uDC20-\uDC7F\uDD00-\uDDEF])+/g
```

I don't know about regular expressions, but i found this And it helped me in `React-Native`

Comment: @marc it seems it is working and you can add it to JS section.

Answer (score -1):

In a lot languages, you can simply enter the unicode symbols into the character class: `[a-zäöüß]` etc.

Comment: That won't help a lot, when he wants to match **all** letters.