# Regex for validating alphabetics and numbers in the localized string

Tags: java, regex, unicode, localization

I have an input field which is **localized**. I need to add a validation using a regex that it must take only alphabets and numbers. I could have used `[a-z0-9]` if I were using only English.

As of now, I am using the method `Character.isLetterOrDigit(name.charAt(i))` (yes, I am iterating through each character) to filter out the alphabets present in various languages.

Are there any better ways of doing it? Any regex or other libraries available for this?

Comment: So you want to handle also languages other than English, right?

Comment: looking for a generic solution **including English**

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392194/how-to-match-the-international-alphabet-english-a-z-non-english-with-a-regu) post the `\w` also works in perl's regular expressions on unicode characters, I dunno if this is so in java regexs.

Comment: `\w` is `A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]`. So, no.

Comment: @beerbajay this is not completely true anymore, its still the standart, but `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` enables the Unicode version of the Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes.

Comment: @ManuPK Please note that using `charAt` in Java is always wrong.  You should be calling `codePointAt`, and adjusting your `i` accordingly.

Comment: @tchrist point taken.Thank you.

Comment: I must point out that you used term "alphabet". I believe, what you really meant is script. BTW. Please be aware, that Regular Expressions mentioned in the answers capture all numerals, including [Roman Numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals). You might also want to read about [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since Java 7 you can use `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`

```
String s = "Müller";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\w+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
} else {
    System.out.println("not found");
}
```

with out the option it will not recognize the word "Müller", but using `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`

> Enables the Unicode version of Predefined character classes and POSIX character classes.

See [here for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)

You can also have a look [here for more Unicode information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/unicode.html) in Java 7.

and here on [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) an overview over the Unicode scripts, properties and blocks.

[See here a famous answer from tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771326/626273) about the caveats of regex in Java, including an updated what has changed with Java 7 (of will be in Java 8)

Comment: Of course this will also match underscores and other connecting punctuation.

Comment: @TimPietzcker thats true, if that matters, then your answer would be the better choice for the OP (+1 for you)

Comment: @TimPietzcker Under `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`, the so-called POSIX classes also match per [UTS#18 Annex C](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties); that is, `\p{alpha}` becomes — if and only if when compiled under the `Pattern` compilation flag —  exactly equal to the Unicode `Alphabetic=True` property, which is itself somewhat complicated but quite useful, and which does not include connector punctuation. Sorry for the run-on sentence. :)

Comment: Just to add to this answer, Unicode Character Class could be enabled via embedded expression ?U, as mentioned in the [Pattern class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).

Answer (score 10):

```
boolean foundMatch = name.matches("[\\p{L}\\p{Nd}]*");
```

should work.

`[\p{L}\p{Nd}]` matches a character that is either a Unicode letter or digit. The regex `.matches()` method ensures that the entire string matches the pattern.

Comment: Other possible unicode categories (e.g. `L` or `N`) can be found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm).

Comment: You don’t need the braces for the 7 major categories. You might also like `\pM`, so `[\pL\pM\pN]`. Note that that is already a broader definition than `\p{Alphabetic}`, because it includes all marks, not just some of them. That puts it closer to the `\p{word}` property used for program identifiers, which per [UTS#18 Annec C](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) is `[\p{alpha}\p{gc=Mark}\p{gc=Digit}\p{gc=Pc}]`, where `\p{alpha}` is complicated, but basically picks only a few of the marks.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Hold on: your boolean test is wrong.  All possible strings match zero or more repetitions of anything. I don’t think you want that star.  Also, as commented elsewhere, although it’s probably want you want, `\pN` is more than just digits; `\p{Nd}` is just decimal digits without Roman numerals, vulgar fractions, or sub- and superscripts, etc. Just call `\pN` any numeric, not any digit, and you’ll be right.

Comment: @tchrist: The `matches()` method requires the regex to match the entire input string, not just a substring. So it only matches if the entire string is composed of letters/digits (or is empty, which arguably fulfills that definition too). Good point about `\p{Nd]}`.

Answer (score 1):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

-- [Jamie Zawinksi](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

I say this in jest, but iterating through the String like you are doing will have runtime performance *at least* as good as any regex — there's no way a regex can do what you want any faster; and you don't have the overhead of compiling a pattern in the first place.

So as long as:

- the validation doesn't need to do anything else regex-like (nothing was mentioned in the question)
- the intention of the code looping through the String is clear (and if not, refactor until it is)

then why replace it with a regex just because you can?

Comment: It would be interesting to back up this claim by measurements.

Comment: +1 well you can agree or disagree, it really an interesting link!

Comment: @Tim: you don't even really need measurements. Unless you're using quantum computing, you can't verify that all characters in a list of characters (aka a String) are letters or digits without visiting each character, and stopping as soon as you find one that isn't. Since this is what the custom code does, it's the minimum possible amount of work. Regexes aren't magic.

Comment: Regexes get things right more often than handcoding does. For example, would you have remembered to use `codePointAt` instead of the erroneous `charAt` that the OP used?  The regex would have already taken care of that for you. Handrolled code can be as tight as a regex, but usually isn’t. It depends on how much time you want to put into crafting it versus how much time the fellow who did the regex library put into doing so. A regex can replace pages of complicated, error-prone code. Always use the regex first, then optimize later only if profiling proves this is needed. Programmer time wins.

Comment: @tchrist: `Always use the regex first, then optimize later only if profiling proves this is needed`. `Programmer time wins`. Those two statements often contradict each other — and a overly complicated regex is frequently present when they do. I agreed completely with the second statement, but not necessarily the first. If we change the word "regex" to "straightforward solution", (a regex is often, but not always the straightforward solution, especially in Java), and then I'd largely agree with you.