# removing all non-printing characters by regex

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I have files which contain non-printing characters such as `\u2066-\u2069` (directional formatting) and `\u2000-\u2009` (spaces of various widths, e.g. `&thinsp;` ). Is it possible to remove (or replace) them by using a (Java) regex? (`\\s+` does not work with the above). I don't want to build this myself as I don't know what characters I might get.

Comment: Did you try `s.replaceAll("(?U)\\s+" , "")`?

Comment: Do you need to remove all Unicode whitespace?

Comment: In Java you can also try [`\P{Graph}+`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for one or more *non visible* characters, same like `[^\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]`. There is further `\P{Print}` available for *non printable*.

Comment: Thanks @bobble bubble . Suggest you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the characters you provided belong to the *Separator, space* Unicode category, so, you may use

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\p{Zs}+", " ");
```

The `Zs` Unicode category stands fro space separators of any kind (see [more cateogry names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) in the documentation).

To replace all horizontal whitespaces with a single regular ASCII space you may use

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\h+", " ");
```

As per [Java regex documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef),

> `\h`       A horizontal whitespace character: `[ \t\xA0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000]`

If you want to shrink all Unicode whitespace to a single space

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?U)\\s+", " ");
```

The `(?U)` is an embedded flag option equal to the [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) option passed to the `Pattern.compile` method. Without it, `\s` matches what `\p{Space}` matches, i.e. `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`. Once you pass `(?U)`, it will start matching all whitespace chars in the Unicode table.

To tokenize a string, you may split directly with

```
String[] tokens = s.split("\\p{Zs}+");
String[] tokens = s.split("\\h+");
String[] tokens = s.split("(?U)\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a [POSIX like `[^[:graph:]]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class) available. For one or more **non visible** characters, try

```
\P{Graph}+
```

The upper P indicates a negation of `\p{Graph}` and would match one or more `[^\p{Alnum}\p{Punct}]` or `[\p{Z}\p{C}]`. Downside is, that it's US-ASCII only [according to the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix). If working with UTF-8 consider using [inline flag](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers) [`(?U)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) or [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499851/regex-for-validating-alphabetics-and-numbers-in-the-localized-string/9500409#9500409).

Just to mention, there is further `\P{Print}` available for **non printable** characters.