# Ajax contact form and UTF-8

Tags: php, ajax, forms, utf-8, contacts

i'm using ajax contact form, downloaded from: http://youhack.me/2010/07/22/create-a-fancy-contact-form-with-css-3-and-jquery/

Everything works ok except UTF as i can't use cyrilic symbols when submitting.

The php:

```
$name = $_POST['name']; // contain name of person
$email = $_POST['email']; // Email address of sender 
$web = $_POST['web']; // Your website URL
$body = $_POST['text']; // Your message 
$receiver = "receiver@domain.com" ; // hardcorde your email address here - This is the email address that all your feedbacks will be sent to 

if (!empty($name) & !empty($email) && !empty($body)) {
    $body = "Name: {$name}\n\nSubject: {$web}\n\nMessage: {$body}";
    $send = mail($receiver, 'Contact from domain.com', $body, "From: {$email}");
    if ($send) {
        echo 'true'; //if everything is ok,always return true , else ajax submission won't work
    }
}
```

It uses jquery.validationEngine-en for validation.
My html already has "Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" in header.

I'm new to php and jquery, so i would appriciate some guidance to make UTF-8 work when submitting.
Thanks :)

**Edit:** When i try to use cyrilic chars (čšćđ) on a required field i get ajax input error "Please use letters only". If i submit the form with cyrilic chars on a non-required field, i receive and email, all letters show ok except cyrilic, which are like this: Å¡.

**Edit 2:** When i set the recipient to gmail (webmail), cyrilic chars show up ok, except in one field, where Ajax doesnt let me use them (regex from Reinder answer).

When i set recipient in outlook (local) and submit the form, none of the cyrilic chars don't show up ok, example: ÄĹĄ oÄa ĹĄ ÄĹ˝Ĺ ÄÄ

**SOLVED** Thanks to Reinder for guide and David! Will solve it today :)

Comment: what do you mean when you say that UTF8 doesn't work?
Does it show correclty in your PHP code when you just output it?
Is the email not displaying correctly?

Comment: when i try to submit with special chars (čšćđ) i get ajax validation error: "Use letters only".

Comment: please update your question with the comment you just gave ;)

Comment: are you using a web-based email client?
And what do you see if you just output the data from the PHP page instead of mailing them?

Comment: Good question, i'll update my question again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

having looked at the plugin you're using, I think this has to do with the validation regex inside jquery.validationEngine-en.js

when the validation is set to 'onlyLetter' it will check using

```
/^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/
```

and none of your characters čšćđ are allowed here...

you need to create a language validation javascript for the language you're using and change that regular expression. For example, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392194/how-to-match-the-international-alphabet-english-a-z-non-english-with-a-regu)

The next thing is to check the encoding of your PHP file and your headers. 
Place this at the top of your PHP code

```
 header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Check if the values are correctly displayed when just outputting them in PHP, like so:

```
echo $name;
```

If they are correctly displayed in the browser and it's just the email that's incorrectly displaying the characters, then you need to pass an encoding header to the email too

example:

```
$headers = "From: $name <$email>\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
$body = "Name: {$name}\n\nSubject: {$web}\n\nMessage: {$body}";
$send = mail($receiver, 'Contact from domain.com', $body, $headers);
```

have a look at the [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on the PHP.NET website

Comment: Good call! That explains the ajax error message. I think changing that regex + sending the mail in utf-8 (using the function in my answer, or one like it) will probably do the trick.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense, thanks Reinder & David!
Would you maybe know with what should i replace that regex so it works? Again, i'm kinda noob in javascript and i will probably just mess it all up :)

Comment: Ajax is working now - i've extended the regex to:
[a-zA-ZŠČĐĆŽščđćž ']+$

I can submit the form now using chars, which are cyrilic. Is that way ok?

Comment: that will definitely work, but it's not a clean solution as you have to manually define all those characters. For what field is this?
Why not just make it a required field?

Comment: It's for the first field - name. It is required. All i need are those chars, defined in new regex, so it should do fine for now :)

Comment: Great! I'll follow your guideline above.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use the default PHP `mail()` function, I've found this come in handy when working with Japanese:

http://bitprison.net/php_mail_utf-8_subject_and_message