# Replace all non-word characters like ?*+#

Tags: javascript, regex, character, match

I need a some help to replace all non-word characters in a string.

As an example `(stadtbezirkspräsident'` should become `stadtbezirkspräsident`.

This Regex should work for all languages so it's kind of tricky because I have no idea how to match characters like `ñ` or `œ`. I tried solving this with

```
string.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>-_{}]/g,' ');
```

but ther are still to many special characters like `Ø` left.

Perhaps there is a general Selector for this, or anybody has solved this problem before?

Comment: Ø is a letter in various languages (Danish, for example) :)

Comment: similar: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392194/how-to-match-the-international-alphabet-english-a-z-non-english-with-a-regu) question. javascript regex doesn't have any native unicode-aware matchers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have define all the Unicode ranges yourself, it's going to be a lot of work.

It might make more sense to use Steven Levithan's [`XRexExp` package with Unicode add-ons](http://xregexp.com/plugins/) and utilize its Unicode property shortcuts:

```
var regex = new XRegExp("\\P{L}+", "g")
string = XRegExp.replace(string, regex, "")
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use trick

```
str.replace(/(?!\w)[\x00-\xC0]/g, '')
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker - I know, but my solution removes special charactrers in low hex range only

Comment: (Yeah, didn't you edit it just as I was writing my comment?) - OK, but there are still enough characters that won't be caught by this (even within the 8-bit ANSI set: `×` and `÷` come to mind).

Comment: The answer is wrong, because it does not distinguish between letters and non-letters in Latin 1 Supplement. Moreover, the question explicitly says: “This Regex should work for all languages”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Even `\p{L}` is not a good one, as it is "category letter", not a non-word class. But anyway, enjoy your dowvotes... I still believe my solution is what OP needs, even I agree that it is not 100% complex and correct.

Comment: I don't think this answer deserves a downvote, either. The problem is not well-defined enough to decide which solution is best.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment to Tim Pietzcker’s answer, but presenting code in comments is awkward... Here’s a simple example of using the XRexExp package:

```
<p id=orig>Bundespräsident / ß+ð/ə¿α!</p>
<p id=new></p>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://xregexp.com/addons/unicode/unicode-base.js">
</script>
<script>
var regex = new XRegExp("\\P{L}+", "g");
var string = document.getElementById('orig').innerHTML;
string = XRegExp.replace(string, regex, "");
document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = string;
</script>
```

For production use, you would probably want to download some versions of the base package and the Unicode plug-in and use them on your server.

Note: The code checks for characters that are not classified as letters (alphabetic) in Unicode. I suppose this corresponds to what you mean by “word character”, though words in a natural language may contain hyphens, apostrophes, and other non-letters.

Beware that characters are added to Unicode, and the category of a character might (rarely) change. The package has been maintained well, though; it corresponds to Unicode 6.1 (version 6.2 is out, but it has no new letters).